# React Native странный вид TextInput в landscape

Tags: react-native

В portrait все нормально, а в landscape ерунда какая-то, как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте пропс: `disableFullscreenUI={true}`

Comment: Заработало, теперь выглядит нормально